# Pop-up Notifications stopped from Google Calendar on Chrome+Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-calendar

Google Chrome on Windows 10.

**Confession**: I severely locked down those bothersome, non-stop Windows 10 notifications.

Afterwards: I still get audio alerts from Google Calendar, but the pop-up alerts (when you're using Google Chrome, in the past a little pop-up would drop down from the address bar to alert you of the Google Calendar item) have stopped.

So, very strange: I still have audio alerts, but no pop-up alerts.

I suspect it has something to do with how I locked down Windows 10's notifications. **My Question**: what adjustments could I make so that, in addition to the audio alerts, I can also continue to receive the pop-up alerts from Google Calendar (while using the Chrome browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Leaving question up, and posting answer here, for future reference.

Windows > Cortana > Notifications & actions settings:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you had Chrome enabled as in the image above, you might need to click on that entry and ensure that "Show notifications in Action Centre" is also enabled

Chrome notifications in Windows Notification Centre:
[image: Chrome notifications in Windows Notification Centre]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145485)